# Override date formatting for a culture in .net

Tags: .net, datetime, string-formatting

We have a problem with the built-in .net date formatting. We are using the abbreviated month format:

```
string.Format("{0:MMM}", date);
```

For our Czech site, it outputs Roman numerals (eg "IV" where in en-GB it would be "Apr"). We want to change this to some custom abbreviations.

What is the best way to do this? I don't really want to put an if statement in the view. Should I use a DateTimeFormatInfo?

Also, how do Microsoft decide on the formatting, is it based on a standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which culture do you want to use? You can just specify it in the call to `string.Format`. For example:

```
string text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:MMM}", date);
```

Note that if that's *really* all you're formatting, it would be simpler to call `ToString`:

```
string text = date.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(That way you don't need all the composite formatting stuff.)

Comment: This is a multi-language site and we set the thread culture based on the browser setting (or cookie). All the other languages output the desired format. It is just the cs-CZ culture that we need to change.

Comment: @JontyMC: In that case, when you set the thread culture maybe you should just special-case cs-CZ to either use a different culture entirely, or one with a different `DateTimeFormatInfo`.

Comment: Is there really no way to change the default. I also have a multilingual site, but the client doesn't like the defaults for some languages.

Comment: @Richard: Change the default what? Culture? Yes... you can change it on a per-thread basis.

Comment: @Jon, sorry for not being clear. I mean change the format used for a culture. We like most of the culture based formats, but would like to change just "D" for some cultures.

Comment: @Richard: Well you can change the culture to a new culture with whatever you want as the ShortDateFormat.

Comment: @Jon is there a way to keep all the other formats for a culture and change just one. Do I need to copy a culture into a new one? Are the standard ones set in stone and not configurable?

Comment: @Richard: The system ones are immutable, but you can use CultureInfo.Clone to create a mutable copy. Just clone the ones you're interested in, and when you set the default culture for a particular request (or whatever you're doing - the context isn't clear) see whether it's one you need a "custom" version of.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I wanted to know, but didn't quite know how to ask.