# How can I override the currency formatting for the current culture for an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, internationalization, formatting, cultureinfo

The currency decimal and thousand separators for the en-ZA region are ',' and ' ' respectively, but the separators in common use are '.' for decimal, plus my user wants ',' for the thousands separator. I wish to set these globally, so that I only have to use the `{0:C}` format string for all my currency fields, without having to any explicit `Format` or `ToString` calls.

I would prefer to be able to do this without changing the culture settings on the web server, as I also need to set the decimal places for currency to zero, as cents are not wanted when reporting on estimates of R100k and up etc. I wouldn't want to arbitrarily set the whole culture to zero places, just one for this application.

In comments to his answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306319/override-date-formatting-for-a-culture-in-net), Jon Skeet suggests cloning the current culture and setting and changing the required settings. I have done this as follows:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
    newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
}
```

However, how to I activate that new culture for all requests the application handles from this point on? Is there another way to achieve what I wish to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having asked many questions and done many experiments, I have decided that it's safe to state that the only way of doing this is to use controls derived from the out of box controls and do your own formatting using a customised culture object. Derive your control from e.g. `BoundField` and provide your own `FormatProvider`:

```
public class BoundReportField : BoundField
{
    protected virtual string GetDefaultFormatString(FieldFormatTypes formatType)
    {
        var prop = typeof(FormatStrings).GetProperty(formatType.ToString()).GetValue(null, null);
        return prop.ToString();
    }

    protected virtual IFormatProvider GetFormatProvider(FieldFormatTypes formatType)
    {
        var info = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        info.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
        info.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "R";
        info.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
        info.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
        return info;
    }

    private FieldFormatTypes _formatType;
    public virtual FieldFormatTypes FormatType
    {
        get { return _formatType; }
        set
        {
            _formatType = value;
            DataFormatString = GetDefaultFormatString(value);
        }
    }

    protected override string FormatDataValue(object dataValue, bool encode)
    {
        // TODO Consider the encode flag.
        var formatString = DataFormatString;
        var formatProvider = GetFormatProvider(_formatType);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formatString))
        {
            formatString = GetDefaultFormatString(_formatType);
        }
        return string.Format(formatProvider, formatString, dataValue);
    }
}
```

I will publish an article later with all the gory details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Application_BeginRequest` event to set the culture for every request. Inside event:

```
var newCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be having any effect.

Comment: just observed on my pc that the default format of NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator and NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator for culture en-ZA are "." and "," respectively, which means that they are already set to the value your are looking for. That is why you are not seeing any difference

Comment: what .NET version are you using? I believe they changed between 3.5 and 4, from what you have to what I have, i.e. 'space' for group and comma for decimals.

Comment: Beware such changes if you upgrade to 4.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similar when migrating some "legacy" .NET sites and services from one web server to another.

I ended up writing an [IIS module](https://github.com/thurstonford/Localize) to enable overriding the hosts currency, number and date/time formats (dictated by the regional settings of the host server) without editing code.

It enables customization of currency symbols, decimal separators, number group separators, long date format, short date format... basically all the properties that can be explicitly set via the NumberFormatInfo and DateTimeFormatInfo objects in .NET. All done via the web.config file (ie: no code changes required).

Hoping this might save somebody some time and/or frustration.