# Override string.format("{0:c}") behavior for certain cultures

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, culture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I override the currency formatting for the current culture for an ASP.NET web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201532/how-can-i-override-the-currency-formatting-for-the-current-culture-for-an-asp-ne)

I have multicultural websites in which I set the culture via the web.config:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-CA"/>
```

This works, except I would like to override the behavior. For example, when referencing currency, all my values are coded like:

```
 decimal price = "12.99";
 String.Format("{0:c}", price);
```

The output would be as expected for en-CA:

```
$12.99
```

But I would want it to be:

```
$12.99 CAN
```

Can this be done globally for a specific culture?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201532/how-can-i-override-the-currency-formatting-for-the-current-culture-for-an-asp-ne

Comment: @ScottE Make it an answer and you'll get the points. Thx!

Comment: the question really should be closed. Thanks though!

Comment: Others normally vote to close. You probably can't delete it now

Comment: Don't be shy, add it as an answer.